# We're getting a new question-asking interface

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange has announced that a [new question-asking interface](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/) is going to roll out to the network on Tuesday.

This experience adds some additional guidance to asking questions, particularly for new users. It appears that it also provides some level of customizability for Exchange sites, like ours, to surface guidance about asking good questions during the ask process. I'm not clear yet on exactly where and how we can customize, but we should find out soon!

Hopefully this is a change that we can harness to effectively introduce new users to our structure as a community and start to close gaps in understanding and expectations. I'm looking forward to it.

**Edit:** Here is the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network) on Meta Stack Exchange. It includes a discussion of which elements of the new-question interface are editable. Edits can only be achieved by Community Managers at SE after achieving consensus on Meta.

Comment: I remember reading about this a few months back. Hope it ends up working well!